# Custom Android calendarView

Tags: android, android-custom-view, calendarview

I am looking for a CalendarView that can be used in a dialog something like this:

[image]

I plan to use `android.widget.CalendarView` but it is available from API level 11.  That's an issue considering there are still lot of users, using android 2.3.3 (but not a major one can let go those set of user).

Which of these options should I use?

1) libraries that are available and use them accordingly.

2) customize the `android.widget.CalendarView`?

If #2, then are there any examples for it?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Hi visit all given links, hope will help you

1. Betterpickers: https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers
2. Calendar Sync: http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2013/05/android-calendar-sync.html
3. Simple Calendar: http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/
4. Caldroid: https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid
5. DateTimePicker: https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker

When you visit [Betterpickers](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers), for a working implementation of this project see the `sample/` folder.

Implement the appropriate Handler callbacks:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements DatePickerDialogFragment.DatePickerDialogHandler {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
  }

  @Override
  public void onDialogDateSet(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    // Do something with your date!
  }
}
```

Use one of the Builder classes to create a PickerDialog with a theme:

```
DatePickerBuilder dpb = new DatePickerBuilder()
    .setFragmentManager(getSupportFragmentManager())
    .setStyleResId(R.style.BetterPickersDialogFragment);
dpb.show();
```

Also for another example you can visit [Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) and use as follows:

To embed the Caldroid fragment in your activity, use below code:

```
CaldroidFragment caldroidFragment = new CaldroidFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
caldroidFragment.setArguments(args);

FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
t.replace(R.id.calendar1, caldroidFragment);
t.commit();
```

Comment: thanks Jitesh i am looking into it and i think the last and the derekbrameyer github are what i am looking for will check them and let u know.. as of now upvoting your answer and when i check and work with them will accept the answer with which library i worked with

Comment: Link number 4 does not work anymore. 404: Page Not Found

Answer (score 4):

hope this help you this is all editable custom calendar you can edit in your way

take fragment

```
public class fragmentCalender extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

ArrayList<calenderModelCustom> itemsArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); // calls function to get items list

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private View mView;
private Context mContext;
private GridView mGridView;
private int temp = 1;
private calenderModelCustom mCalenderModelCustom;
private ImageButton mPreviousButton, mForwardButton;
private int mPageCount = 0;
private TextView mYearLable;
private int mYear;
private Calendar mCalender;
private int mCurrentDay, mCurrentMonth, mCurrentYear;
private ArrayList<calenderModelCustom> list;
private String mFirstDate;

public fragmentCalender() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment fragmentCalender.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static fragmentCalender newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    fragmentCalender fragment = new fragmentCalender();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_calender2, container, false);
    mContext = this.getActivity();
    Util.CAL_CUR_DATE_CNST = "0";
    mCalender = Calendar.getInstance();
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    //initialize xml element object
    initializeView();
    //current things
    setCurrentEnv(mCalender.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    //current date
    getDateTime();
    //actions
    initializeViewAction();
    //set adapter
    initializeViewAdapter(mPageCount, Util.CAL_CUR_DATE_CNST);


    return mView;
}

/*
* setting first date,day of current month
* */
private void setCurrentEnv(int mCurrentMonth){
    Log.i("<<>>Cal",String.valueOf(mCurrentMonth));
    Date date = new Date();
    date.setDate(1);
    date.setMonth(mCurrentMonth);
    date.setYear(mCurrentYear);
    mFirstDate = getDay(date);
    Log.i("<<>>Cal",mFirstDate);
    if (mFirstDate.contains("Fri")) {
        mPageCount = 4;
        initializeViewAction();
        initializeViewAdapter(mPageCount, Util.CAL_CUR_DATE_CNST);
    } else if (mFirstDate.contains("Sat")) {
        mPageCount = 5;
        initializeViewAction();
        initializeViewAdapter(mPageCount, Util.CAL_CUR_DATE_CNST);
    } else if (mFirstDate.contains("Sunday")) {
        mPageCount = 6;
        initializeViewAction();
        initializeViewAdapter(mPageCount, Util.CAL_CUR_DATE_CNST);
    } else if (mFirstDate.contains("Mon")) {
        mPageCount = 0;
        initializeViewAction();
        initializeViewAdapter(mPageCount, Util.CAL_CUR_DATE_CNST);
    } else if (mFirstDate.contains("Tue")) {
        mPageCount = 1;
        initializeViewAction();
        initializeViewAdapter(mPageCount, Util.CAL_CUR_DATE_CNST);
    } else if (mFirstDate.contains("Wed")) {
        mPageCount = 2;
        initializeViewAction();
        initializeViewAdapter(mPageCount, Util.CAL_CUR_DATE_CNST);
    } else if (mFirstDate.contains("Thu")) {
        mPageCount = 3;
        initializeViewAction();
        initializeViewAdapter(mPageCount, Util.CAL_CUR_DATE_CNST);
    }
}

private void initializeViewAction() {

    if (mCurrentMonth == 1) {
        mYearLable.setText("Jan " + String.valueOf(mCurrentYear));
    } else if (mCurrentMonth == 2) {
        mYearLable.setText("Feb " + String.valueOf(mCurrentYear));
    } else if (mCurrentMonth == 3) {
        mYearLable.setText("Mar " + String.valueOf(mCurrentYear));
    } else if (mCurrentMonth == 4) {
        mYearLable.setText("Apr " + String.valueOf(mCurrentYear));
    } else if (mCurrentMonth == 5) {
        mYearLable.setText("May " + String.valueOf(mCurrentYear));
    } else if (mCurrentMonth == 6) {
        mYearLable.setText("Jun " + String.valueOf(mCurrentYear));
    } else if (mCurrentMonth == 7) {
        mYearLable.setText("Jul " + String.valueOf(mCurrentYear));
    } else if (mCurrentMonth == 8) {
        mYearLable.setText("Aug " + String.valueOf(mCurrentYear));
    } else if (mCurrentMonth == 9) {
        mYearLable.setText("Sep " + String.valueOf(mCurrentYear));
    } else if (mCurrentMonth == 10) {
        mYearLable.setText("Oct " + String.valueOf(mCurrentYear));
    } else if (mCurrentMonth == 11) {
        mYearLable.setText("Nov " + String.valueOf(mCurrentYear));
    } else if (mCurrentMonth == 12) {
        mYearLable.setText("Dec " + String.valueOf(mCurrentYear));
    } else {
        mYearLable.setText("" + String.valueOf(mCurrentYear));
    }
    mForwardButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //increment current month by one
            mCurrentMonth++;

            //if current month >= 13 then start from first month
            if (mCurrentMonth >= 13) {
                mCurrentMonth = 1;
                mCurrentYear ++;
            }
            setIfBackOrForwardToCurrentMonth();
            setCurrentEnv(mCurrentMonth);
        }
    });

    mPreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //increment current month by one
            mCurrentMonth--;

            //if current month >= 13 then start from first month
            if (mCurrentMonth < 1) {
                mCurrentMonth = 12;
                mCurrentYear --;
            }
            setIfBackOrForwardToCurrentMonth();
            setCurrentEnv(mCurrentMonth);
        }
    });

    mGridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(mContext) {
        public void onSwipeTop() {
            Log.i("top","");
        }
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            //increment current month by one
            mCurrentMonth++;

            //if current month >= 13 then start from first month
            if (mCurrentMonth >= 13) {
                mCurrentMonth = 1;
                mCurrentYear ++;
            }
            setIfBackOrForwardToCurrentMonth();
            setCurrentEnv(mCurrentMonth);
        }
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            //increment current month by one
            mCurrentMonth--;

            //if current month >= 13 then start from first month
            if (mCurrentMonth < 1) {
                mCurrentMonth = 12;
                mCurrentYear --;
            }
            setIfBackOrForwardToCurrentMonth();
            setCurrentEnv(mCurrentMonth);
        }
        public void onSwipeBottom() {
            Log.i("bottom","");
        }

    });



}

/*
* parameter to set current date marker on calender
* */
private void setIfBackOrForwardToCurrentMonth() {
    Log.i("<<>>Cal<>",mCurrentMonth+"  "+Util.CURRENT_DATE);
    if (mCurrentMonth==mCalender.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1){
        Util.CAL_CUR_DATE_CNST = "0";
    } if (mCurrentMonth!=mCalender.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1){
        Util.CAL_CUR_DATE_CNST = "1";
    }
}

/*method to get current date and store it separetely in variable*/
private String getDateTime() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();
    mCurrentDay = mCalender.get(Calendar.DATE);
    mCurrentMonth = mCalender.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    Util.CURRENT_DATE = String.valueOf(mCalender.get(Calendar.DATE));
    Log.i("<<>>Cal<>",Util.CURRENT_DATE);
    mCurrentYear = mCalender.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}

/*
* current day to print in text format
* */
public static String getDay(Date date) {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE"); // the day of the week spelled out completely
    System.out.println(simpleDateformat.format(date));

    return simpleDateformat.format(date);
}

private void initializeViewAdapter(int temp , String mVisibility) {

    CalenderAdapterView mCalenderAd = new CalenderAdapterView(mContext, generateItemsList(temp),Util.CURRENT_DATE,mVisibility);
    mGridView.setAdapter(mCalenderAd);

}

private ArrayList<calenderModelCustom> generateItemsList(int temp) {
    list.clear();
    String itemNames[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items_name);

    for (int i = 0; i < temp; i++) {
        list.add(new calenderModelCustom("", ""));
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < itemNames.length; i++) {
        list.add(new calenderModelCustom(itemNames[i], itemNames[i]));
    }

    return list;
}

private void initializeView() {
    mYearLable = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.currentDateLabel);
    mForwardButton = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_forward);
    mPreviousButton = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_previous);

    mGridView = (GridView) mView.findViewById(R.id.cal_grid_view);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
    }
    }

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

define grid view in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/marginRight"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendarHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_previous"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_date_back"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_forward"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_date_next"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentDateLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/btn_previous"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/btn_forward"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <!-- eventDays header -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendar_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/calendarHeader"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mondayLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/monday"
            android:textColor="@color/daysLabelColor" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tuesdayLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/tuesday"
            android:textColor="@color/daysLabelColor" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wednesdayLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/wednesday"
            android:textColor="@color/daysLabelColor" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thursdayLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/thursday"
            android:textColor="@color/daysLabelColor" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fridayLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/friday"
            android:textColor="@color/daysLabelColor" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/saturdayLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/saturday"
            android:textColor="@color/daysLabelColor" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sundayLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/sunday"
            android:textColor="@color/daysLabelColor" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/calendar_header"
        android:id="@+id/cal_grid_view">

    </GridView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

create Util.class and write constants

```
public static String CAL_CUR_DATE_CNST ;
public static String CURRENT_DATE ;
```

create Adapter for grid view

```
public class CalenderAdapterView extends BaseAdapter {
Calendar mCalender = Calendar.getInstance();
private Context context; //context
private ArrayList<calenderModelCustom> items; //data source of the list adapter
private String mCurrentDate;
private String mVisibility;
//public constructor
public CalenderAdapterView(Context context, ArrayList<calenderModelCustom> items, String currentDate, String mVisibility) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    this.mCurrentDate = currentDate;
    this.mVisibility = mVisibility;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    //returns total of items in the list
    return items.size(); 
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    //returns list item at the specified position
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // inflate the layout for each list row
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).
                inflate(R.layout.calendar_item, parent, false);
    }

    // get current item to be displayed
    calenderModelCustom currentItem = (calenderModelCustom) getItem(position);


    // get the TextView for item name and item description
    TextView textViewItemName = (TextView)
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_item_name);
    ImageView mImageBaground = (ImageView)
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_baground);

    //sets the text for item name and item description from the current item object
    textViewItemName.setText(currentItem.getmNoOfDays());
    if (mVisibility.equals("0")) {
        if (String.valueOf(mCalender.get(Calendar.DATE)).equals(currentItem.getmNoOfDays())) {
            mImageBaground.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_cur_date);
        }
    }

    // returns the view for the current row
    return convertView;
}
}
```

create xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/img_baground"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_item_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_item_description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

and one drawable file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">

<size
    android:width="30dp"
    android:height="30dp"
    />

<stroke android:width="0.5dp"
    android:color="@color/monsoon"/>

</shape>
```

and create class

```
public class calenderModelCustom {

private String mStartPos;

public String getmStartPos() {
    return mStartPos;
}

public void setmStartPos(String mStartPos) {
    this.mStartPos = mStartPos;
}

public String getmNoOfDays() {
    return mNoOfDays;
}

public void setmNoOfDays(String mNoOfDays) {
    this.mNoOfDays = mNoOfDays;
}

private String mNoOfDays;

public calenderModelCustom (String mStartPos,String mNoOfDays){
    this.mStartPos = mStartPos;
    this.mNoOfDays = mNoOfDays;
}
}
```

add in string.xml

```
<string name="monday">M</string>
<string name="tuesday">T</string>
<string name="wednesday">W</string>
<string name="thursday">T</string>
<string name="friday">F</string>
<string name="saturday">S</string>
<string name="sunday">S</string>

//calender
<string-array name="items_name">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>11</item>
    <item>12</item>
    <item>13</item>
    <item>14</item>
    <item>15</item>
    <item>16</item>
    <item>17</item>
    <item>18</item>
    <item>19</item>
    <item>20</item>
    <item>21</item>
    <item>22</item>
    <item>23</item>
    <item>24</item>
    <item>25</item>
    <item>26</item>
    <item>27</item>
    <item>28</item>
    <item>29</item>
    <item>30</item>
    <item>31</item>

</string-array>
```

add dependency for card

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
```

write down the scope of implementation guys

Comment: use this method to get current date in setCurrentEnv()            private String FirstDayOfMonth(int mCurrentMonth, int mCurrentYear) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 25);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mCurrentMonth);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, mCurrentYear);

        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        Date firstDayOfMonth = cal.getTime();

        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEEEEE");
        
        return sdf.format(firstDayOfMonth);
    }
                                              to get current date

Comment: can you give download url?