# Scroll up and down similar to CalendarView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

Hi I have implemented my own calendar using the help of [Custom Android Calendar](http://goo.gl/vRqIym) Now I am implement the scroll up and down view for getting previous or next months calendar similar to CalendarView API. I am sure this possible as it can be done through calendarView.

Can somebody direct me to right page to implement this? Do I need Gestures or scrollView?

If I use ScrollView inside the gridview - I am not able to get the calendar properly the view gets cut automatically!

```
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:numColumns="7"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

    </ScrollView>
```

Let me know!

Comment: Doesn't scroll view make difference in scrolling if the calendar is half the screen?

Comment: I just tried the scrollView the gridView is coming up very small. Updated the question.. Please check!

Comment: go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873472/custom-android-calendarview

Answer (score 1):

I used the Gestures UP and DOWN and solved the issue. With some help from SIMPLE GESTURE LISTENER SAMPLE! Thanks!
!

Answer (score 0):

@TheDevMan,if you are pointing to this view[image: Calender app's scroll effect] This is called Parallax Effect. There are many libraries which can help you.

- [ParallaxEveryWhere](https://github.com/Narfss/ParallaxEverywhere) ([Demo app on playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fmsirvent.ParallaxEverywhereSample))
- [ParallaxScrollView](https://github.com/chrisjenx/ParallaxScrollView/downloads)
- [nirhart's parallaxScroll](https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll)
- [AKparallax](https://github.com/ygorbarboza/AKParallax-Android)

(Each library project contains guidelines which will help you for respective library.)

Particularly ParallaxEveryWhere is impressive. But you should adopt on bases of your usage.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. actually I am not looking Stock Calendar App view. I am looking at CalendarView API which is there in SDK. Just a simple GridView with Scroll is required. If I swipe up it should go to next Month if swipe down it should go to previous month.

Comment: So I want to know how the swipe up and down can be achieved. In SDK's calendarView swipe up and down work just fine.