# Change the style of Android Calendar View

Tags: android, calendarview

I am using a calendar view inside a dialog fragment .I am getting the one as shown below. I am using the default calendarview provided.

[image: Actual Calendar View]

But instead i want to get a calendar view as this one , which is shown by default in xml when i add:

[image: Desired Calndar View]

I have tried changing the style to Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.CalendarView , Widget.Material.CalendarView but with same effect.

Comment: my answer helped you or not

Comment: @HarshSharma thanks it helped

Comment: Mention not @Gaurav. Love to hear from you that it really helped after so much long duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know How to create Custom Calendar but you might check this GitHub library.You may succeed in creating the one, you are asking for with just little customization

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

And also Refer to this Useful Stackoverflow post from which you will definitely be able to implement a CalenderView as you wanted.

[Custom Android calendarView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873472/custom-android-calendarview)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **prolificinteractive materialcalendarview** library, to change header style for year and month.

check my answer here:
[How can I change Android MaterialCalendarView month color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45432524/how-can-i-change-android-materialcalendarview-month-color/57663591#57663591)

Answer (score 0):

At first I didn't understand why CalendarView component looks different in Android Studio and on my phone, but then I found this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/45368436/11052714

So the reason you are seeing this on your phone is because of API level. In the post I mentioned above, however I think wrong API level is mentioned, because I have the old calendar view with Android version 5.0.2 aka API level 21. It means that still in API level 21 old Calendar View visual look is used.