# How can I change Android MaterialCalendarView month color?

Tags: c#, android, calendar, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin Android MaterialViewCalendar
[image]

Month header dissappears on some devices, so I want to set it's color manually.

```
<com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:mcv_showOtherDates="all"
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I change Android MaterialCalendarView month color?

When you use `MaterialCalendarView`, there are three different text appearances you can set :

- Header

  mcv_headerTextAppearance or setHeaderTextAppearance()
- Weekday

  mcv_weekDayTextAppearance or setWeekDayTextAppearance()
- Date

  mcv_dateTextAppearance or setDateTextAppearance()

The header text appearance is used for the **topbar month label**. The weekday is for the row of weekday labels, and date is for the individual days.

You could use `mcv_headerTextAppearance` or `setHeaderTextAppearance()` to set the `MaterialCalendarView` month color. For more information, you could read he [document](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/docs/CUSTOMIZATION.md).

Usage like this :

```
materialCalendarView.SetHeaderTextAppearance();
```

or

```
app:mcv_headerTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextAppearance"
```

Comment: For header background clor https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z16zO.png. how can i change

Answer (score 4):

Step 1:

In styles add your own style

```
<style name="CalendarWidgetHeader">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Step 2:

```
calendarView.setHeaderTextAppearance(R.style.CalendarWidgetHeader);
```